# Why doesn't calling replace on a pandas dataFrame not act on the original object?

Tags: python, pandas, object

If you look at the following simple example:

```
import pandas as pd 
l1 = [1,2,'?']
df = pd.DataFrame(l1)
df.replace('?',3)
```

Why does this not replace the '?' in the dataframe df?
Wouldn't the object that is referred to by df be affected when replace is called on it?

If I write:

```
df = df.replace('?',3)
```

Then  df.replace returns a new dataFrame that has replaced the value of ? with 3.

I'm just confused as to why a function that acts on an object can't change the object itself.

Comment: It can!  But the devs decided that the default ought to be that it returns a copy rather than editing in place.  IMO, this is the safer bet.  However, you can use `replace` to alter the object itself if you use the appropriate parameter.  You can easily find that by looking at the [**documentation**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `inplace=True`:

```
df.replace('?',3, inplace=True)
print (df)
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```